# Custom build cmake using standard library also for project with lower gcc version

Tags: c++, c, cmake, linker

I have a custom build cmake v3.10.0 which was compiled with a `gcc_4.8.3`. I am using this custom build cmake to compile a cmake project that must use `gcc _4.1.2` because of legacy code.

Executing cmake promted me with an error because it needs to use the `libstdc++-IFX.so.6` provided by `gcc_4.8.3` which I fixed by adding the path to the correct library in my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before the path to the libraries provided by `gcc_4.1.2`.

Compiling my project and linking an executable (which is done by c++) results in the linker taking the `gcc_4.8.3` stdlibs over the `gcc_4.1.2` libs. Is there any way to tell cmake to not use the libraries it needs for himself for my cmake project preferably without touching `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`?

**Edits:**

@squareskittles comment: I did read and try everything this post suggest but without any changes. The `libstdc++-IFX.so.6` is still taken from `gcc_4.8.3`

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6581357/linking-to-stdc-with-cmake-and-gcc-4-1-2). You can set the `CC` and `CXX` variables. Or you can edit your CMake file(s) to manually add the libstdc++ library from the older compiler using `target_link_libraries`.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your build system?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding `-static-libstdc++` to your CXX_FLAGS or CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS?

Comment: @nega yes I did try to add `-static-libstdc++` to my cxx flags but this has no effect. What do you want to know abut the build system ? primarily standard gcc 4.1.2

Comment: OS? Linux? if so, what distro? how are the compilers installed? do you have `root`?

Comment: have you tried building your cmake with `-static-libstdc++` and then wiping your gcc_4.8.3 chain?

Comment: RHEL 5, compilers are preinstalled and no i do not have permanent root access. When i build cmake i followed the instructions given by https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/tree/v3.13.4 i am not sure if i have the possibility to use `-static-libstdc++`